# How to get the name of a button pressed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I have 2 `<div>`s of at least 81 buttons, all with the same class, but they have different ids and names. I am trying to figure out how to alert the name of the current button that was being pressed.

Comment: `alert(buttonElement.id + " " + buttonElement.name)`?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, I kept getting [object HTMLCollection].

Answer (score 0):

```js
function runMe(e){
  return function(){
    console.log(e.getAttribute("id"));
  }
}

var eles = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")
Array.prototype.forEach.call(eles,function(ele){
  ele.onclick = runMe(ele);
})
```

```html
<button id="a1" class="myButton">A1</button>
<button id="b2" class="myButton">B2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way by using `this.name` inside the click handler function:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('Name of the cliked button is:', this.name)
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" id="btn1" name="btnName1">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" name="btnName2">Button 2</button>
 
  <!--------- More Buttons--------->
</div>
<div>
  <!--------- More Buttons--------->
 
  <button type="button" id="btn48" name="btnName48">Button 48</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn49" name="btnName49">Button 49</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn50" name="btnName50">Button 50</button>
  
  <!--------- More Buttons--------->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the buttons with the same class name and assign the `click` event listener to each buttons so that when you click the button the listener is invoked:

```js
function btnClick(){
 console.log(this.id + " " + this.name);
}

var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('myButton');
for(i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++){
   allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', btnClick);
}
```

```html
<button id="1" class="myButton" name='name1'>B1</button>
<button id="2" class="myButton" name='name2'>B2</button>
<button id="3" class="myButton" name='name3'>B2</button>
<button id="4" class="myButton" name='name4'>B2</button>
<button id="5" class="myButton" name='name5'>B2</button>
```